# Disabling a button in jquery if a checkbox is not checked and the input field is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some checkboxes and input fields genreated through PHP dynamically and they are

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($checks as $m => $check) {
  $textinbox ='<input type="text" class="message_input"/>' ;
  if ($truck->truck_category == 2) {
    $checkbox .='<input type="checkbox" value="'.$check->id.'"/>' ;
  }else{
    $checkbox .='<input type="checkbox" value="'.$check->id.'er"/>' ;   
  }

 ......other php statements here

echo "<tr  id='" . $m . "'>";
echo "<td>" . $m . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
echo "<td>".$checkbox."</td>";
echo "<td>".$textinbox."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

I also have a button

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="approve_btn">Approve</button>
```

I would like to disable the button if:

- a checkbox is not checked and `$textbox(textinput)` is empty

I would like to enable the button if:

- The checkbox is checked  OR
- The checkbox is unchecked and the `$textbox(textinput)` is not empty

FOR ALL CHECKBOXES AND INPUT BOXES IN THE DOM

I have tried this but fails to work (it works from top to bottom - that is if i enter all the input fields the button is enabled but if i delete the lower ones at the bottom the button is still enabled:

I would like it to work even if one deletes input field for the lower items

```
$('input[type=text]').on("change", function(){
//check other input fields to ensure that the ones with unchecked checkboxes have input values
var uncheckedboses = $(":checkbox").not(":checked");
uncheckedboses.each(function() {
  if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val()=="" >0){

      $("#approve_btn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  else {
      $("#approve_btn").removeAttr("disabled"); 
  }
  });  
    console.log(uncheckedboses);  

});
```

The logic am looking foward to achieve is this:

```
$('input[type=text]').on("change", function () {

// check other input fields to ensure that the ones with
// unchecked checkboxes have input values 

if (/*above comment is true*/) {
  //disable the btn
} else { 
  //enable the btn
}
```

Comment: To change the disabled property, use `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.prop("disabled", false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the button disabled by default and add two events one checkbox check event and other textbox onchange event. Add your logic in these events and done.

```
// Event for checkboxes
$(".someCheckBox").on('change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    // You custom logic will come here
    $('#someButton').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#someButton").attr('disabled', true);
  }
});

// Event for textBoxes
$(".someTextBox").on('change keyup paste', function() {
  if($(this).val()) {
    $('#someButton').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#someButton").attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works only for the first checkbox and input boxes but i would like to listen to all items not only the first checkbox and input box worked on

Comment: I have updated the question with the logic am tryng to achieve

Comment: `disabled` is a property... Use `.prop()`. ;)

Comment: And it would be better to use classes instead of ids, since there is multiple checkboxes an inputs. Classes should be defined in the PHP loop.

Comment: This is just a generic solution. I didn't give you a solution specifically tailored for your need. You can make changes to the logic to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To stay close to the logic you want...

```
$('input[type=text]').on("change", function(){

    //check other input fields to ensure that the ones with unchecked checkboxes have input values
    var uncheckedboses = $(":checkbox").not(":checked");
    var flag = false;

    uncheckedboses.each(function() {
        if( $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val()=="" ){
            flag = true;
        }
    });

    // If ONE unchecked checkbox is found with an input empty...
    if ( flag ){
        $("#approve_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
        $("#approve_btn").prop("disabled", false);
    }

    console.log(flag);
    console.log(uncheckedboses);  
});
```

**Your logic is ok...**
Since you only want to verify inputs that have their associated checkbox unchecked... And verify them all.

But you have to use a "flag" since you run a loop.
Like a postal box filled by the postman. ;)

If you don't and the last unchecked checkbox HAS an input filled, the button would be enabled even if there is some (previous in the loop) with an empty input.

If ONE unchecked checkbox is found with an input empty, the flag is `true`.
Then, disable the button.

Like I said in comments below your question 1 hour ago, the simple correct use of `.prop("disabled", [true/false])` is fixing your most evident issue.

Have a look at your condition too.

```
if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val()=="" >0){
```

should be:

```
if( $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val()=="" ){
```

Comment: But I' not sure about the changed values in the inputs that have a checkbox checked... If it gets emptied... This script will not notice it.